# Why do I receive JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference from Crystal Report Viewer?

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

I am developing an ASP.Net application and I am using Crystal Report for Visual Studio for development of reports. I am receiving an error message whenever I navigate to another page in a multi-page report.

This error only appears whenever I code a `ReportDocument.Dispose()` or `ReportDocument.Close()` call in the `Page_Unload` event of the page that contains the Crystal Report Viewer control. I want to include this call because I want to proactively manage the disposal of the ReportDocument objects. Without this, after the application is used for awhile, I am receiving "Load Report Failure" exceptions when attempting to load the Crystal report.

Here's a little more information. I am loading the report in the `Page_Init` event of the page. When a report is run, I am storing the `ReportDocument` object into a session variable. Thereafter, whenever a user navigates to another page of the report, the `Page_Init` (as well as the `Page_UnLoad`) method is again called. I then check if the session variable for this "Tab" of the report exists. If it does, I set the source of the report to it (after casting it into a `ReportDocument` object).

I am getting several errors whenever I try to navigate to another page: 
On the server side, I am getting a "object reference not set to an instance of an object". On the client side, I am receiving the following errors:

```
//<![CDATA[
bobj.crv.stateManager.setComponentState('CrystalReportViewer1__UI',eval('('+document.getElementById('__CRYSTALSTATECrystalReportViewer1').value+')'));
WebForm_InitCallback();new bobj.crv.ViewerListener('CrystalReportViewer1__UI',new bobj.crv.AspDotNetAdapter("__doPostBack('CrystalReportViewer1','VIEW-CONTEXT')", "VIEW-CONTEXT", "__CRYSTALSTATECrystalReportViewer1","WebForm_DoCallback('CrystalReportViewer1','arg','cb','ctx','errcb',true)","4.0.30319.34237"));//]]>
```

I am also receiving a server side error:

> "Invalid report file path. (CrystalDecisions.Shared)"

How can I use the Dispose or Close method on the ReportDocument object so that these errors will not occur in my situation?

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and Crystal Reports for Visual Studio 13.0.10.1385.
Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Can you debug and find out from which line of code that you are getting these errors? And, it's not a good idea to save the ReportDocument in session. Use Cache instead. Refer this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms225516(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Also read this http://scn.sap.com/thread/3193093

Comment: Sam - Thanks. Your second reference was excellent. In terms of putting the ReportDocument in Session, I have to disagree. The articles you pointed to say that cache is used only when the report has high "sharability". These reports do not. In any case, it would probably exhibit the same behavior. I did debug the program and, I am getting the error only when, in the PAge_Unload event, I have coded a RptDoc.Dispose(). The second reference you made supports the idea that this is a bug in the Crystal Report Viewer.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be related to the session value being converted (casted) to a ReportDocument type. Is something stopping you from using cache?